# References for construction of $\Bbb R$ and and real-exponent powers

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, reference-request

I would like to know if anyone has a good and rigorous reference for the following constructions:

- construction of $\Bbb R$ as a simply ordered field and as a linear continuum (Dedekind Property or Least Upper Bound Property);
- construction of $\Bbb R$ as the completion of $\Bbb Q$;
- construction of real-exponent powers (i.e.: $x^{\alpha}, x > 0, \alpha \in \Bbb R$), preferably without using the exponential function.

The motivation behind this request is that I have familiarized with most of these constructions because they were quoted or partly left as exercises on books I have read, however I have never felt satisfied with them.

---

As always any comment or answer is well-accepted and let me know if I can explain myself clearer!

Comment: At the end of the first chapter of Walter Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis there is an appendix that constructs $\mathbb{R}$ from $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: For some textbooks books that are primarily devoted to the construction of the real numbers, see my answer to [Is the real number structure unique?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2249868/13130) For references (papers and books) that deal with the history of this topic and/or various methods for carrying out the construction, see my answer to [History of the construction of $\mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/111717/13130).

Comment: https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/anal1v.pdf this book constructs $\mathbb{R}$ from $\mathbb{Q}$ using Cauchy sequences. It also defines real powers, though using the exponential function. It seems that constructing a continuous power function and constructing the exponential function are equivalent tasks, and since the exponential works in greater generality, I guess it is presented.